# BEM Convention for css

Tags: html, css, frontend, conventions

I am a beginner for BEM Convention. I have watched so many video about it but when it comes to coding i am a bit confused.

Here is the header section for a website:

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="header__logo-box">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="header__logo">
                <h1 class="header__tittle">Happy Years</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="header__navbar">
                <ul class="header__navbar-list">
                    <li class="header__navbar__item">
                        <a href="" class="header__navbar__link">More Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__navbar__item">
                        <a href="" class="header__navbar__link">How it works</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        
   </header>
```

So i have logo with h1 and 2 links. Is BEM convention is okey here?

Thank you

Comment: Are you read about BEM from official documentation? https://en.bem.info/

Comment: nope. I will read it now. What do you think about my code anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code  it's the right BEM structure

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="header__logo-box">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="header__logo">
                <h1 class="header__title">Happy Years</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="header__navbar">
                <ul class="header__navbar-list">
                    <li class="header__navbar-item">
                        <a href="" class="header__navbar-link">More Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__navbar-item">
                        <a href="" class="header__navbar-link">How it works</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
   </header>
```